# Nextflow with Azure Batch - Cannot find a matching VM image

Tags: azure, azure-batch, nextflow

While trying to set up Nextflow with Azure Batch (NF-Core), I am getting following error. I tried this on multiple workflows (sarek, ataseq etc.) I get the same error -

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.0
Pulling nf-core/atacseq ...
 downloaded from https://github.com/nf-core/atacseq.git
Launching `https://github.com/nf-core/atacseq` [rhl6d5529] DSL1 - revision: 1b3a832db5 [1.2.1]
Downloading plugin nf-azure@0.13.1
----------------------------------------------------
                                        ,--./,-.
        ___     __   __   __   ___     /,-._.--~'
  |\ | |__  __ /  ` /  \ |__) |__         }  {
  | \| |       \__, \__/ |  \ |___     \`-._,-`-,
                                        `._,._,'
  nf-core/atacseq v1.2.1
----------------------------------------------------

Run Name             : rhl6d5529
Data Type            : Paired-End
Design File          : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nf-core/test-datasets/atacseq/design.csv
Genome               : Not supplied
Fasta File           : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nf-core/test-datasets/atacseq/reference/genome.fa
GTF File             : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nf-core/test-datasets/atacseq/reference/genes.gtf
Mitochondrial Contig : MT
MACS2 Genome Size    : 1.2E+7
Min Consensus Reps   : 1
MACS2 Narrow Peaks   : No
MACS2 Broad Cutoff   : 0.1
Trim R1              : 0 bp
Trim R2              : 0 bp
Trim 3' R1           : 0 bp
Trim 3' R2           : 0 bp
NextSeq Trim         : 0 bp
Fingerprint Bins     : 100
Save Genome Index    : No
Max Resources        : 6 GB memory, 2 cpus, 12h time per job
Container            : docker - nfcore/atacseq:1.2.1
Output Dir           : ./results
Launch Dir           : /
Working Dir          : /nextflow/atacseq/rhl6d5529
Script Dir           : /.nextflow/assets/nf-core/atacseq
User                 : root
Config Profile       : test,azurebatch
Config Description   : Minimal test dataset to check pipeline function
Config Contact       : Venkat Malladi (@vsmalladi)
Config URL           : https://azure.microsoft.com/services/batch/
----------------------------------------------------
Uploading local `bin` scripts folder to az://nextflow/atacseq/rhl6d5529/tmp/66/bd55d79e42999df38ba04a81c3aa04/bin
[-        ] process > CHECK_DESIGN -

[-        ] process > CHECK_DESIGN [  0%] 0 of 1

[-        ] process > CHECK_DESIGN [  0%] 0 of 1
Error executing process > 'CHECK_DESIGN (design.csv)'

Caused by:
  Cannot find a matching VM image with publisher=microsoft-azure-batch; offer=centos-container; OS type=linux; verification type=verified




[58/55b7f7] process > CHECK_DESIGN (design.csv) [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1
Error executing process > 'CHECK_DESIGN (design.csv)'

Caused by:
  Cannot find a matching VM image with publisher=microsoft-azure-batch; offer=centos-container; OS type=linux; verification type=verified
```

I tried looking into the source code of nextflow. I found the error to be in `AzBatchService.groovy` (line number below).

https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/blob/0e593e6ab82880810d8139a4fe6e3c47ff69a531/plugins/nf-azure/src/main/nextflow/cloud/azure/batch/AzBatchService.groovy#L442

I did some further digging in my Azure Batch account instance. Basically, I wanted to confirm if the list of supported images being received from the Azure Batch account has the one that is required for this pipeline. I could confirm that the server did indeed respond with the required image -

[image]

What could be the issue here? I remember running the exact same pipeline a few weeks back and it did work a few times. Am I missing something?

Comment: Might be a configuration problem. What command line did you use? The [azurebatch.config](https://github.com/nf-core/configs/blob/master/conf/azurebatch.config) profile needs some command line params set, `--az_location`, `--batch_name`, etc. Were these set correctly?

Comment: https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/issues/2846

Comment: @Steve - That's a link to exactly my issue ;-) Also, I checked, and all the parameters are provided correctly. Clueless about what's going on, unfortunately. Little to no support from the Nextflow end as well.

Comment: Not sure if my answer helps, but you could also try contacting the nf-core people if you're still stuck. Someone there might be able to help troubleshoot over Slack.

Comment: I think this should be fixed in [v22.04.1](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/releases/tag/v22.04.1). Are you able to test a newer Nextflow?

Comment: Yes Steve. That's the fix I was awaiting for. Thanks a lot for the responses so far. @Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had another look through the [Azure Cloud](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/azure.html) docs and think this might be relevant:

> By default, Nextflow creates CentOS 8-based [pool nodes](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/azure.html#pool-nodes), but this
> behavior can be customised in the pool configuration. Below the
> configurations for image reference/SKU combinations to select two
> popular systems.
>
> - Ubuntu 20.04:
>
> ```
> sku = "batch.node.ubuntu 20.04"
> offer = "ubuntu-server-container"
> publisher = "microsoft-azure-batch"
> ```
>
> - CentOS 8 (default):
>
> ```
> sku = "batch.node.centos 8"
> offer = "centos-container"
> publisher = "microsoft-azure-batch"
> ```

I think the issue here is a mismatched `nodeAgentSkuId`. Nextflow is expecting a CentOS 8 node agent SKU, but you have a CentOS 7 SKU. If it's not possible to change the `nodeAgentSkuId` somehow, the node agent SKU that Nextflow uses should be able to be overridden by adding this to your [`nextflow.config`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/edge/config.html):

```
azure.batch.pools.<name>.sku = 'batch.node.centos 7'
```

Where `<name>` is the pool identifier:

> `azure.batch.pools.<name>.sku`
>
> Specify the ID of the Compute Node agent SKU which the pool identified with `<name>` supports (default: `batch.node.centos 8`, requires `nf-azure@0.11.0`).

https://www.nextflow.io/docs/edge/azure.html#advanced-settings

Comment: Adding to that, `nextflow` team has identified the issue and rolled out a fix in the version `22.04.1`